# Algebraic multiplicity of Complex solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Just wondering how to know the Algebraic multiplicity of Complex solutions..

For example : $(x^2+2)^3$

The solutions are: $i\sqrt{2}$ , $i\sqrt{-2}$

How can I see what is algebraic multiplicity of these solutions?

is it $3$ for both of them or less?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, it is $3$ for both.

Comment: Thanks a lot, strange I couldn't find the answer in the internet and my professor didn't mention it too

Comment: @Roach87 It isn't strange at all. If you don't know a name of the general principle you are using (which I don't think has an actual name) you are unlikely to find your specific exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$x^2 + 2 = (x-i\sqrt 2)(x + i \sqrt 2)$$

In this expression, each have multiplicity $1$. However, since you seek their results in the cube, you have

$$(x^2 + 2)^3 = (x-i\sqrt 2)^3(x + i \sqrt 2)^3$$

which clearly shows each has multiplicity $3$ for the polynomial you care about.

Comment: Yeah makes sense ,Thank you